# Removal of gaps in expresssion

Tags: spacing, formatting

I have an expression in a body of LaTeX:

`$O(\mid\emph{P}\mid+\mid\emph{Q}\mid+\sqrt{nk})$`

Which produces:

[image]

This is correct but is it possible to remove the gaps between the characters at all?

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Do you want to re-write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `| |` directly from keyboard, that is `|P|` instead of `\mid P \mid`. Or `\| P \|` if you wish.

```
$O(|P|+|Q|+\sqrt{nk})$ or $O(\|P\|+\|Q\|+\sqrt{nk})$
```

Finally, do not use `\emph{}` in math mode.

Comment: `\|` is quite different from `|`

Comment: @egreg, but is it used for norm, isn't?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: `\lvert` and `\rvert` are another possibility.